# How can I change the focus when I minimize a window?

Tags: window, focus, minimize

I use very often the shortcut "alt+tab" to change the focus between windows, however, every time I minimize a window and press "alt+tab" it takes the focus back on the window I've just minimized - and it's very annoying.

I'll make a clearer example: let's say I have 3 windows opened (A, B and C) and I'm working mainly on A and B switching frequently between them using alt+tab. Then I go and check something on C and after that I minimize it. Here when I press alt+tab the focus goes back to C, whereas I would like to push the focus to the end after I minimize a window, so that when pressing alt+tab I see that window at the end of the array and not as the next option.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Windows of the same application or of different applications? Alt+tab in Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity), but also  later (Gnome Shell) uses an application switcher, not a ("traditional") window switcher that does not differentiate on the app to which a window belongs. Only in 19.10 (I believe) Ubuntu uses a windows switcher for Alt Tab, which should behave like you want. Using Compiz Config settings manager, you can enable other window switchers, including a "traditional" one.

Comment: Windows of any application, however I don't get why this is important. If I wanted to switch between windows of the same application I'd use "alt+` " but the problem would remain the same. I don't know any other switcher and it's not clear to me what makes "traditional" a switcher. Any further information is appreciated, in the meanwhile thanks for your help.

Comment: Iif you pres Alt+Tab+Tab then A appears and another Tab makes B appear though. The windows don't maximize until you release Alt correct? As such it doesn't seen like a big issue.

Comment: That's right, that's how it behaves. However I don't see how knowing that it's not such a big issue for you might be helpful to solve the problem.